# Arch Linux - No Audio anymore ( Alsamixer / Pulsaudio )

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I am not 100% if it is because of updating with pacman -Syu or simply because something else happened but since today my audio output is not working. 
I am dual booting with windows and with windows sound is working as intended.

This is how my alsamixer and pavcontrol look like: 
[image: pavcontrol]

[image: alsamixer]

As you can see, when I actually play some sound via aplay or simply start a youtube video, pavcontrol shows me that there is some sound coming in. **But no output.**

Comment: Try `alsamixer -c1` -- alsa controls of first sound card.

Comment: @Oxyd gives me 'invalid card index 1' error.

Comment: @FoolishExcalibur try `-c0` card.

Comment: @Oxyd https://imgur.com/a/y6fDT9l 
This is how it looks like